# XML Schema: Element with attributes containing only text?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm having difficulty searching for this. How would I define an element in an XML schema file for XML that looks like this:

```
<option value="test">sometext</option>
```

I can't figure out how to define an element that is of type `xs:string` and also has an attribute.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<xs:element name="option">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Try

```
  <xs:element name="option" type="AttrElement" />

  <xs:complexType name="AttrElement">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string">
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception on trying your code - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot r
esolve the name 'AttrElement' to a(n) 'type definition' component. Why is that so?

Comment: If that is so, it is probably because your schema document has a target namespace and you will need to use a prefixed name to point to the type.  (If the prefix `tns` is bound to the schema document's target namespace, you will use `type="tns:AttrElement"` to refer to the type.)

Comment: @Ashwin you might need to reference the type with the type namespace (`type="tns:AtrElement"` if your default namespace of the XSD is xs not the targetNamespace of the document. Typically in that case `tns` is defined and used.

Answer (score 86):

... or the inline equivalent:

```
<xs:element name="option">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I find it really unintuitive to define `simpleContent` within a `complexType`. But then again it's XSD, where nothing seems really intuitive. Thanks nonetheless! :-)

Comment: This will show an error for me in *IntelliJ* (*V12.1.3*): The value attribute is "not allowed". Using **complexContent** instead of **simpleContent** fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is not the same, but it works for me:

```
<xsd:element name="option">
    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
        <xsd:attribute name="value" use="optional" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```