# XML Schema causing XQuery error: 'text()' is not supported on simple typed element

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery-sql

BAII have written the following XML schema (partial):

```
<xs:schema>
...
<xs:element name="Fields" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Field" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:attribute name="seq" type="xs:int" default="0" />
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
</schema>
```

I am trying to write an XML Schema that will allow me to query the text() property of the Field element using the XML Data Type in SQL Server 2012.

The Field element contains only text values and attributes (no other elements) and is the only descendant of the Fields element.

I tried changing the `<simpleContent>` to `<complexContent>` but then I'm not sure how to define the base attribute needed in the extension tag.

The XQuery was:

```
WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.xxxx.com' as ns) 
SELECT [BAI].query('/ns:XxxFile/ns:Record/ns:Fields/ns:Field/text()')
FROM [dbo].[BTRS]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376582/xml-schema-element-with-attributes-containing-only-text) on Stack Overflow.

I was having a tough time figuring out how to handle the Field element that had attributes and no elements. I erroneously thought the only thing to do was tag the content as **simpleContent** or **complexContent**. The only thing that was required was to add the **mixed** attribute to the **complexType** tag and set it to true. I changed the above **Schema** portion as follows:

```
<xs:schema>
...
<xs:element name="Fields" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Field" minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
          <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" default="Unknown" />
          <xs:attribute name="seq" type="xs:int" default="0" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
</schema>
```

I can now access the Field element's text content in the XQuery query.