# XML Schema: Element with restricted content and attribute with defined values

Tags: xml, xsd

So i have an element `phone`

```
 <phone carrier="A">9991234567</phone>
```

with a `carrier` attribute with defined values. I've defined it using complexType. Now, the content of the phones also needs to have a restriction (Regex).

```
<xs:element name="phone" type="phoneType" />

<xs:complexType name="phoneType">
    <xs:attribute name="carrier" type="carrierType" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="carrierType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
        <xs:enumeration value="A" />
        <xs:enumeration value="B" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a "complex type with simple content". For an example see

[XSD : How to use both value and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147502/xsd-how-to-use-both-value-and-attribute/29147732#29147732)

But in your case the base type is not `xs:string`, rather some restriction from string. So define your restricted type, for example

```
<xs:simpleType name="phoneNr">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and then define `carrierType` as an extension of `phoneNr` (the extension being the attribute).