# XSD Problem with Type Attribute : The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType

Tags: xml, types, xsd

I've looked all over stackoverflow for an answer for this, but unfortunately all the ansers didn't work for me:

I have the following xml:

```
<STGDocument version="3" workitem-id="0" index="1">
       <ID type="String">ab78e02c-a472-45b9-99d0-57c19034a51b</ID>
....
```

And the XSD generated from a webpage :

```
<xs:element name="STGDocument">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
.......
```

Somehow the `<xs:element name "Id" ....>` Tag throws an error "The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType"

How can i fix this?

As mentioned before, I tried all the solutions on SOF but none of them worked for me...

Thnaks

Comment: I now removed the type attribute in <xs:element> and now it complains because the ID element in the XML contains string

Comment: Now it complains : The element cannot contain text. Content model is empty.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of an element is declared EITHER using a `type` attribute (like `type="xs:string"`) OR using a nested `xs:simpleType` or `xs:complexType` element. You can't have both, which is why it is complaining.

The actual type of your ID element is a "complex type with simple content", and should be declared as in this example: [XSD : How to use both value and attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147502/xsd-how-to-use-both-value-and-attribute/29147732#29147732)