# Right way to defined element with attribute in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD to validate an element like this:

```
<productColor Colortype="HEX">353535</productColor>
```

so, I tough by my self it is so easy, I do something like this:

```
    <xs:element name="productColor" type="xs:string">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Colortype" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="HEX"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="RGB"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="sRGB"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="CMYK"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="HSV"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

But, but when I've done some search I found out some body (like [this link in W3](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_simpleContent.asp) ) defined attribute but using extension , like this code:

```
<xs:element name="productColor">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="Colortype" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="HEX"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="RGB"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="sRGB"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="CMYK"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="HSV"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Why? It is wrong if we go in my way?(don't use extension) and I found [this link 
from Microsof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7f0tkwcx(v=vs.80).aspx)it  which says you can do it without extension.
So now, I am totally confused.

Comment: see [XML Schema: Element with attributes containing only text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376582/xml-schema-element-with-attributes-containing-only-text)

Comment: @Kachna i saw this, but what about the Microsoft link?

Comment: the Microsoft link does not say : you can do it without extension.

Comment: @Kachna but in the link, they have an example without extension.

Comment: If you talk about `<xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer" />`. the quantity element is an element with text-only and doesn't have an attribute.

Comment: I think you know that a complex type element is an XML element that contains **other elements and/or attributes**.

Comment: @Kachna yes, yes, i know it. and no i am talking about  this:    `<xs:element name="OrderInfo">`. OrderInfo is an element witch contain 2 other element and have an attribute, so basically OrderInfo is an complex element. i am wounder why they didn't use  extension to add attribute, as w3 say.

Comment: see [this](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/22/easyschema.html)

Answer (score 0):

A data types can be either named (i.e., global) or anonymous (i.e., local). Global definitions must have a name and be a top-level element that is included directly in the `xs:schema` document element. Local types are defined directly where they are needed in a schema; they are anonymous (i.e., no name attribute); and they have a local scope.

In your case, the `productColor` element has two types (which is wrong) :

1. the `xs:string` predefined simple datatype.
2. the local complex type (anonymous).

Complex types with **simple content** models are created by adding a list of attributes to a simple type. The operation of adding attributes to a simple type to create a **simple content complex type** is called an extension of the simple type. see [xs:simpleContent Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256106%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)