# how to define an element with attribute in xsd having a sequence

Tags: xml, attributes, complextype

This may be close to duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376582/xml-schema-element-with-attributes-containing-only-text). But this is not the same. After reading the above answer I know what code must be added for my scenario, but I am unable to figure out where to put it. This is my current `xsd` file

```
<tns:element name="WSO2Lanka">
    <tns:complexType>
        <tns:sequence>
            <tns:element name="Employees" type="EmployeeBaseType">
            </tns:element>
        </tns:sequence>
    </tns:complexType>
</tns:element>

<tns:complexType name="EmployeeBaseType">
    <tns:sequence>
        <tns:element name="Employee" type="EmployeType">
        </tns:element>
    </tns:sequence>
</tns:complexType>

<tns:complexType name="EmployeType">
    <tns:sequence>
        <tns:element name="name" type="nameType">
        </tns:element>
        <tns:element name="company" type="tns:string"></tns:element>
        <tns:element name="position" type="tns:string"></tns:element>
        <tns:element name="address" type="addressType"></tns:element>
        <tns:element name="tele" type="tns:string"></tns:element>

    </tns:sequence>

</tns:complexType>

<tns:complexType name="nameType">
    <tns:sequence>
        <tns:element name="fname" type="tns:string">
        </tns:element>
        <tns:element name="lname" type="tns:string">
        </tns:element>
    </tns:sequence>
</tns:complexType>

<tns:complexType name="addressType">
    <tns:sequence>
        <tns:element name="city" type="tns:string"></tns:element>
        <tns:element name="province" type="tns:string"></tns:element>

    </tns:sequence>
</tns:complexType>
```

and this is what I needed in my `xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WSO2Lanka xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../EmployeeXMLSchema.xsd">
    <Employees>
        <Employee eid="001">
            <name>
                <fname>kasun</fname>
                <lname>Siyambalapitiya</lname>
            </name>
            <company>WSO2</company>
            <position>intern</position>
            <address>
                <city>Kuliyapitiya</city>
                <province>North Western</province>
            </address>
            <tele>0715523333</tele>
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
</WSO2Lanka>
```

As in the `xml` I need to have an attribute for the element `Employee` as `eid`of the type of `ID`
 I know that the below code is the one to be added, can you please help me to figure this out. Thanks in advance

```
<tns:complexType>
    <tns:simpleContent>
        <tns:extension base="tns:ID">

            <tns:attribute name="edi" type="tns:ID" use="required"></tns:attribute>

        </tns:extension>

    </tns:simpleContent>
</tns:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try by updating "EmployeType" as below (added attribute in complexType after close of sequence element) ?

```
<tns:complexType name="EmployeType">
<tns:sequence>
    <tns:element name="name" type="nameType">
    </tns:element>
    <tns:element name="company" type="tns:string"></tns:element>
    <tns:element name="position" type="tns:string"></tns:element>
    <tns:element name="address" type="tns1:addressType"></tns:element>
    <tns:element name="tele" type="tns:string"></tns:element>

</tns:sequence>
<tns:attribute name="eid" type="tns:string"/>
```

Added below line in your "EmployeeType" definition.

```
***<tns:attribute name="eid" type="tns:string"/>***
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it later and let you know if it worked